# Laravel 5: differentiate if new row inserted in DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

how can I differentiate if new row inserted or not using Laravel `DB::insert()`?, my query:

```
$return = DB::insert("
     INSERT IGNORE INTO groups
     (uid,name)
     VALUES
     ({$uid},'{$name}')
");

echo $return; // 1 in both cases
```

I found in both cases if new row inserted returns `1` and if not (because of duplication of primary key) returns `1` too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use INSERT IGNORE, just use a regular INSERT statement or a model insert, and wrap it in an exception handler. If the exception triggers then the insert did not create a new row.

Comment: I don't want to fire exception, I want to continue the process, whether new row inserted or not.

Comment: This is the easiest way. Wrap the `try/catch` around just this line of code and use `finally{}` (PHP >5.5) to continue the process if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use strict comparison operator to distinguish boolean 1 from literal 1.

For example:

```
if ($insert === true) {
// this will only run if the insert is successful
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `DB::insert()` returns a boolean from `PDOStatement::execute()` ,
and when returns true it means the statement was "successful," but it doesn't mean it changed anything. It just means there was no error.

i suggest to get inserted id and then test if it exist or not :

```
$return = DB::insert("
         INSERT IGNORE INTO groups
         (uid,name)
         VALUES
         ({$uid},'{$name}')
    ");

$lastId = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

if($lastId!=0){
    // it exist ..
}
```

Comment: class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'insertGetId' https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#inserts

Comment: The `insertGetId` method is part of the QueryBuilder https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insertGetId you'd have to specify an array of parameters when using it and it doesn't have any way to specify the IGNORE condition. There has been some discussion on it but the answer was to just use raw queries https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9612 which doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Yes, i can see what is the problem now. i have a suggestion though, i hope it can help

Comment: As a workaround you can better use `int DB::affectingStatement(string $query, array $bindings = [])` for every query type. It will return the row count of affected tuples. Relying on the `lastInsertId()` might mean that if you insert into different tables, the ID just happens to remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Either you retrieve the lastInsertedId() by checking the comparison or you can also use **Laravel Observers** over there, so that if any thing will get inserted into database, the observer will be called automatically from Model.

Comment: Just a note. This is part of Eloquent, which for example is by default not enabled in Laravel Lumen. Also, having your logic split like this rots your mind, since the case where rows are actually inserted is probably the default case. PHP does not have built-in support for things that make that easier, such as co-routines. Better use `int DB::affectingStatement(string $query, array $bindings = [])`

Answer (score 0):

Building on @delatbabel's answer, if you're creating code which is procedural, you can use something like this:

```
$insertOK = false;
try{
         DB::insert("
         INSERT groups
         (uid,name)
         VALUES
         ({$uid},'{$name}')");

    $insertOK = true;

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
    //Damn something went wrong.. handle this problem
    }


if($insertOK)
{
//Do some more things if you know the insert is OK.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can better use `int DB::affectingStatement(string $query, array $bindings = [])` for every query type. It will return the row count of affected tuples.

Was already available in Laravel 4.x